# GDAL for Python: how can I get XYZ surface from a Geotiff?

Tags: python, gdal

I want to get an XYZ-like surface from a Geotiff with GDAL in Python.

I do the following:

1) Get some geotiff from here: http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SELECTION/inputCoord.asp

2) Write the script:

```
from osgeo import ogr, osr, gdal

file_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname("/home/felix/dump/srtm_62_05.tif")
gdal_data = gdal.Open(file_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
raster_band = gdal_data.GetRasterBand(1)
raster = raster_band.ReadAsArray()
```

Okay, it works and even gives me some data in `[latitude, longitude --> some_strange_elevation_units]` format.

I want to convert this raster to some `X[i,j], Y[i,j], Z[i, j]` surface. And I need the units to be scaled in meters. How can it be done?

P.S. I use GDAL 2.1.3

Comment: What height units does your data srtm_62_05.tif use?

Comment: Meters. But they are calculated not from simple sea level, but from some strange point. Also, when there is sea on the map, the elevation is about -32000, and I don't know why...

Comment: Data providers usually have also metadata about their products. I would read first everythig from http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/index.asp. My guess is that about -32000 means a hole in the data, "nodata".

Comment: It's -32768, not -32000. This is explicitly stated on the CGIAR site (and read/understood by GDAL) to be the No Data (null) value.

Comment: Duplicate of Stack Overflow question [GDAL for Python: how to get a cartesian XYZ surface in meters from a Geotiff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247752/gdal-for-python-how-to-get-a-cartesian-xyz-surface-in-meters-from-a-geotiff)

Comment: ReadAsArray() returns an array of elevations in meters (not lat, long). The numbers are usually integer. Special number, -32768, represents the location in the sea and ocean. If you want to do the conversion you must specify a map projection to use.